# Multiple Validators for a single field

Tags: python, validation, web2py

I have a table nsksystem which is getting value for its two field nskmachinename and nskreleaseid from another table nskrelease.
The requirement is nsksystem.nskreleaseid + nsksystem.nskmachinename should be unique and nsksystem.nskreleaseid is from nskrlease database. I am not enforcing any constraints in table.

```
db.define_table('nsksystem',
    Field('nskuserid',length=512,requires=IS_EMAIL(error_message='invalid email!'),default = auth.user.email if auth.user else None, label=T('Email ID'),writable=False),
    Field('nskmachinename', length=128, requires = IS_IN_DB(db,'nskrelease.nskname','%(nskname)s',error_message='Machine not registerd for release.'), label = T('Machine Name')),
    Field('nskpassword', 'password', length=512,readable=False, label=T('Machine Password')),
    Field('nskreleaseid',length=128, default='',label = T('Release'))
)

db.nsksystem.nskreleaseid.requires = [IS_IN_DB(db,'nskrelease.releaseid'), IS_NOT_IN_DB(db(db.nsksystem.nskmachinename == request.vars.nskmachinename), 'nsksystem.releaseid', error_message='Machine is already registered to the specified release.')]
```

In the above code the first require is enforced but I dont see a drop down for

```
IS_IN_DB(db,'nskrelease.releaseid')
```

And for the second require, when i try to give a conflicting input instead of giving me the desired error, a ticket is issued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the `IS_IN_DB` validator in a list, it will no longer generate the select widget. Instead of putting the validators in a list, you can use the `_and` argument:

```
db.nsksystem.nskreleaseid.requires = IS_IN_DB(db, 'nskrelease.releaseid',
    _and=IS_NOT_IN_DB(db(db.nsksystem.nskmachinename == request.vars.nskmachinename),
                      'nsksystem.releaseid',
                      error_message='Machine is already registered to the specified release.'))
```